# compactMap() closure fails when adding irrelevant NOP declaration?

Tags: swift, closures, declaration

Playground

XCode Version 13.3 (13E113)

Swift 5.6

---

First print of `compactMap()` closure displays this:

```
["What\'s", "Going", "On?"]
```

The second print displays this:

```
[(), (), ()]
```

Seems like if I declare anything inside the closure, the output of the closure changes.

```
print(  "What's\nGoing\nOn?".split(separator:"\n").enumerated().compactMap
{ idx, lineText in
    lineText
})

print(  "What's\nGoing\nOn?".split(separator:"\n").enumerated().compactMap
{ idx, lineText in
    let _ : String
    lineText
})
```

Is there a way to wrap some of it to hide the other declaration?

Is the closure confused about the type?

Is there any way to unconfuse it (or me)?

Is it a Swift bug?

Issue is root of why other things I'm trying to with this pattern aren't working.

### UPDATE

As per @Shadowrun's answer below, I added a return statement in the 3rd example, but that leads to compile time errors. So is *that* resolvable?

```
print(  "What's\nGoing\nOn?".split(separator:"\n").enumerated().compactMap
{ idx, lineText in
    let _ : String
    return lineText
})
```

expression failed to parse:
error: test playground.playground:38:52: error: generic parameter 'ElementOfResult' could not be inferred
print(  "What's\nGoing\nOn?".split(separator:"\n").enumerated().compactMap

```
                                       ^
Swift.Sequence:2:28: note: in call to function 'compactMap'
    @inlinable public func compactMap<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Self.Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]</b>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a one line closure there's an implicit return, so the first one is returning lineText which is of type string.  See "Functions With an Implicit Return" at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

The second one doesn't actually return anything, once it is more than one line, there is no implicit return.  So the return type is Void which is also spelled as the empty tuple, () and that's what you get there.

You need to say `return lineText` explicitly if you mean to return something.

This function:

```
{ idx, lineText in
    let _ : String
    lineText  // This line evaluates the value of lineText and does nothing with the result
}
```

does not return a value.  Any function that doesn't return a value returns a Void value. Void is a type with only one possible value, called ().  Mapping to void is a pointless thing to do.  Even if your function did a side effect, like printing something, it wouldn't be good style to use map just for side effects.

You can guard against this kind of mistake by being more explicit about the return type in the closure

```
{ idx, lineText -> String in ... }
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I do recall reading that, and forgot about that w.r.t. to this, however, in the specific case above that doesn't solve it, as adding return generates compile time errors. I'll update the question, since your answer, while correct, relevant and useful doesn't solve the problem (so far).

Comment: In the first case it's mapping them to substrings, if you want an array of Strings, then you want  { idx, lineText -> String in 
    return String(lineText)
}

Comment: A little tip to debug: break your instructions like that: `let initialString = "What's\nGoing\nOn?"; let splitted = initialString.split(separator:"\n"); let enumerated = splitted.enumerated(); let compactetd1 = enumerated.compactMap { idx, lineText in lineText }; let compacted2 = enumerated.compactMap { idx, lineText in let _ : String; lineText }` (where ";" is for a new line), and use the Type Inference (see https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID457), then go on mouse over the variable with Alt (until a question mark pop), and click, you'll see the type.

Comment: Also you don't need compactMap because the closure doesn't return an optional.  And you don't need .enumerated() because the closure ignores the index.  You can just use ".map" on the "splitted" substrings

Comment: @Shadowrun this is just a reduction of a much more complex thing I'm doing with `AttributedString` and a switch statement that *does* require the index.

Comment: @Shadowrun `enumeration().compactMap { }` is a pattern floating around out there as a trick for getting the index and value, and `map()` wouldn't work in that case, but you were correct to point out in my provided example it was overkill/irrelevant.

Comment: .enumerated() gets you the (zero-based) index and value tuples, and you can map those with  .enumerated().map { }.  You only need to "compact" the "map" if the function you are mapping returns an optional and you want to remove any nil values.  Using compactMap with a function that doesn't return an optional is a bit odd.